# SSL CSR for server farm on IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, web-farm, server-farm, iis-arr

I have 2 IIS web servers with my website hosted. I have a 3rd server with IIS for ARR. I have created a server farm with name  ABC.com on 3rd server and added the 2 IIS web servers to the farm. Disabled SSL offloading for security purpose.
My website name is https ://www.ABC.com.   I have mapped my website name to IP address of 3rd ARR server.
Correct me if I am doing wrong.
I want the request flow to have https throughout the request.
Now in which server should I create CSR request for SSL certificate, and where all should I install the SSL certificate.
Only 1 SSL is required or multiple SSL certificates are needed?
Should I use ABC.com  farm name while creating CSR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I found that SSL has to be created on IIS Webserver seperately and IIS ARR server separately. And they have to be installed on the respective servers where created.